# How to setup libgdx with eclipse?

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to make a game using libGDX game library which should run on android devices. I don't want to use android studio. I want to use eclipse ide.

When I run libgdx-setup.jar, it asks for android sdk's location, but I am unable to find android sdk's download link in the official website.

Comment: eclipse is unsupported for android development now.

Comment: @Almo so only android studio ?

Comment: If you want a supported IDE, yes. You can use Eclipse, but it's not supported for android dev. Personally I don't like to use unsupported software. :)

Comment: Google **libgdx android setup** before asking. It will be faster than asking and at least then it shows some research effort.